# Angular / Typescript using the parameter value from method as a js object value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am using Ionic / Angular / Typescript and I want to dynamically state the value of a location by the value passed from the method in the parameter.

Here is the code:

```
async fileWrite(location) {
    try {
      const result = await Filesystem.writeFile({
        path: `test.txt`,
        data: `This is a test`,
        directory: location,
        encoding: FilesystemEncoding.UTF8
      });
      alert('Wrote file' + result);
    } catch (e) {
      alert('Unable to write file' + e);
    }
  }
```

As you can see:

directory: location,

location contains a value so it's a variable.

I'm passing it like this:

```
<ion-button (click)="fileWrite('FilesystemDirectory.Cache')">FileWrite to Cache</ion-button>
```

For some reason it's not passing as a variable.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `FilesystemDirectory` has to be member property of associated .ts file. Try to remove quotes. `'FilesystemDirectory.Cache'` -> `FilesystemDirectory.Cache`

Comment: Says: FilesystemDirectory is not defined

Comment: Are you using @capacitor/core?

Comment: Yes, like this: import { Plugins, FilesystemDirectory, FilesystemEncoding } from '@capacitor/core';

const { Filesystem } = Plugins;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this.

In your typescript class, right before constructor.

```
directory = FilesystemDirectory;
```

and then inside you template.

```
<ion-button (click)="fileWrite(directory.Cache)">FileWrite to Cache</ion-button>
```

Hope this helps.